# How to copy build XMLs from Master to the Slave node in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I have created a Jenkins job which used to run in the master and I have the `build.xml` file in the master.

Now I have added a slave node and added the setting `Restrict where this project can be run` so that my job always runs on a particular slave.

Now my build jobs are failing and I can see:

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on demo_slave_inst2 (slave1) in workspace /root/slave/workspace/demo_job
FATAL: Unable to find build script at /root/slave/workspace/demo_job/autobvt.xml
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Recording test results
Finished: FAILURE
```

This autobvt.xml file already exists in the master. So looks like I need to copy this file over to the slave node manually which does not looks like quite handy.

How I can instruct jenkins to copy this as part of the build?

Comment: Is autobvt.xml file not checked-in in your version control tool? Where exactly is it present on master?

Comment: it resides on the master node

Comment: Are you using any version control tool such as Git, Perforce, SVN etc?

Comment: Glad to see that you resolved the issue. Please accept your answer or the one given by @Waman so that the question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted the issue using the [Copy to Slave](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Copy data to Workspace" http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Data+To+Workspace+Plugin using which you can copy the files from master to slave and run them as a part of build process (No manual effort needed!)